# 120v power supply section 220v adaptation

Tags: voltage, transformer, components, rectifier

[image]

I'm building a very simple tube overdrive, power supply section of the schematic can be seen above. as you can see the circuit has been designed for 120v. I will be dealing with 220v instead of 120v, and my question is:

to get 210v B+ what kind of values would I need to change as far as components are concerned (apart from the transformers)? like in the rectifier portion, and the other components in the power supply section?

sorry for the nooby question but I'm still learning

thanks!

Comment: Presumably just change the first transformer to have a 220V primary and 12.6V secondary. The rest can the same as after that point the input voltage is irrelevant. I suppose the fuse value will need to be rated for 220V an trip at half the current.

Comment: I can't buy a 120v transformer, I will have to get it custom wound. It's much easier for me to buy the transformers cheap and modify the circuit.

Comment: Can you get a centre tapped 240V one?

Comment: not really, It'd be easier to get a custom wound one.

Comment: Can you not obtain a standard dual primary, universal voltage power transformer?!  Where on this planet are you?

Comment: I have read this three times and I am confused about what you can and can't get, and what you have already. Do you already have this 120V circuit, or just the design?

Comment: well, when it comes to that, I could just get a 120-12v transformer wound, that's not really a huge issue, but I can get only 220v transformers immediately and for a couple of bucks. which brings me to my initial question of how to change the components so that the power supply section can accomodate 220 volts instead of 120. If I could get a 120v transformer, I wouldn't really be asking questions online now would I? ;)

Comment: I doubt your problem is that difficult to solve. But I cannot for the life of me understand the constraints on the problem. What kind of transformer can you get easily (I mean what is the rated primary and secondary voltage of the transformer you want to use, and does it have a split secondary as shown in your schematic?). Also, what line voltage is actually available to you, 110 or 220?

Comment: The right hand transformer that supposedly produces 210V DC with respect to chassis. I estimate that it will be more like 337V DC. This undermines the question somewhat.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the circuit and are trying to modify it then either:

- Replace the leftmost transformer in the circuit diagram with one with a 220V primary. Also replace the fuse with one rated for half the current, and check that the lamp is OK at 220V, and replace if not. Or:
- Obtain a small 220V to 120V step down transformer, and connect that so it provides 120V to the input. Or:
- If you don't need the 12.6Vac out from between the transformers, and the transformers are both rated for 220Vac, then rearrange the rectifier to be a standard one instead of a voltage doubler (i.e. connect the bottom diode to the bottom of the transformer instead of the top, and remove the lower capacitor)

If you don't already have the circuit built, then there are easier ways to get the voltages you need.

Comment: how would I get the voltages with 220v transformers?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Are you asking how I would get those voltages if designing the circuit from scratch?

Comment: ok, let's try this:

Comment: I am building this circuit from scratch. the circuit takes the 120v from the second transformer and ends up with 210v B+ to the valve. I need to get 210V B+ to the valve as well, but I can only use 220v transformers.

Comment: I still don't quite follow. Do you have access to 220 to 12.6 transformers? How about 220V 1:1 transformers?

Comment: I need that 12.6 volts for the valve's filament.

Comment: Also do you actually need 210Vdc on B+? Because I'm pretty sure the circuit you have in your question will provide 338Vdc without load.

Comment: yes, the 210v is the plate voltage that is required by the valve. I need that 338v that you've calculated to be 210v. My guess was a few component changes should take care of it, but it apparently is a vexing problem.... or whatever. I'm getting confused myself. I'm going to work this out by trial and error. thanks everyone for the help.